# Setting due dates for autogenerated cases

Tags: businesshours, sales

Based on a business days value (1 = business day 1, 12=business day 12) and taking account of the below I would like to generate a due date based on a created date. 
 - Default business hours, 
 - Standard holidays
 - Leap year additional days

Namely I create a case on Business day 1. Each case will have a field denoting which business day it is due on, let's take BD5 as an example. When inserting the new record, I would like a Case deadline field to be populated with a datetime value that is 5 business days from the create date at 5pm. I would like those days to exclude non business hours and any holidays I have added into the standard holidays list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first define Business Hours in this screen considering holidays too.

[image: Business Hours]

To calculate and use this Business Hours, Create a separate class for this.

```
public with sharing class BusinessHoursServices {
    //retrieves & assign the Organization level Business Hours to defaultBH 
    static BusinessHours defaultBH {
        get {
            if (defaultBH == null)
                defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours 
                            WHERE IsDefault = true];
            return defaultBH;
        }
        private set;
    }

    //it takes the input date and SLA value and return the calcuated date
    public static Datetime getSLATimeByBusinessHour (DateTime input, 
                                Integer SLAhours) {
        return BusinessHours.add(defaultBH.Id,input, 
                            SLAhours* 60 * 60 * 1000L);
    }
}
```

And during case creation, calculate end date-time using `getSLATimeByBusinessHour` method.

For more information, refer [BusinessHours class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm)